# how to find the domain of this function:$f(x)=\frac{\ln(4-x^2)}{\ln(x+1)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, solution-verification

I'm having trouble solving this exercise: (find the domain of this function) $$f(x)=\frac{\ln(4-x^2)}{\ln(x+1)}$$
Here is my attempt:

1. I've found the domain of the natural logarithm in the numerator, which is equal to: $$4-x^2>0$$ (it must be strictly positive),

   1.1 $$-x^2>-4$$

   1.2 $$x^2<4$$

   1.3 (result) $$-2<x<2$$
2. I've found the domain of the natural logarithm in the denominator, which is equal to: $$x+1>0$$

1.1 (result) $$x>-1$$

Now, I have to find the interval (on the number line) in which each possible solution is acceptable. So, I've plotted each result on a number line, here is the result:

$$-1<x<2$$

but this question has these possible solutions (it is a multiple choice question):

(1)  $-1<x<2, except\space0$

(2)  $-\infty<x<-1$

(3) $-2<x<-1$

(4) $-\infty<x<0$

The solution is $(1)$, but I don't understand why is not 0 included in the solution's interval.

EDIT (correct answer):

In the denominator I would have had considered the equation involving the denominator: $\ln(x+1)=0$. it mustn't be equal to 0.
this error occurs because of distraction.

Comment: Notice thta $\ln(x+1)=0\iff x=0$, so you must avoid null denominators.

Comment: ah, okay, so it was an error of distraction. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At $x=0$ we have $\ln (1-0) = \ln (1) = 0$ in the denominator, which is undefined.